# Laravel Auth - post methods /login not doing anything

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to use Laravel's Authentification. I changed the User.php:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $connection = 'db';
    protected $table = 'db.member';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nom', 'email', 'pwd',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'pwd', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

It seems like it is redirecting to get http://127.0.0.1/login so nothing happens.

http://127.0.0.1/login : **get** works but **post** doesn't, so I get the message "These credentials do not match our records."
I tried changing, in web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::auth();
```

But nothing happens so I need to add Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@create'); myself.

I am wondering where the controller methods are set?

I use laravel 5.8 so AuthController have been replaced by LoginController and  RegisterController (I am wondering if register is still the right method)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: that routes are created by default, if you want to add new logic, you must to overwrite the functions register and login inside authController

Comment: Thanks Felipe, it seems like we don't have the same version cause I don't have AuthController but RegisterController.
Also it seems like the post method doesn't give anything...
POST     | register                         |                       | Closure                                                                | web

Answer (score 0):

within your terminal or cmd, goto your project root and type the following command:

`php artisan make:auth`

after that try visiting your `http://127.0.0.1/register`

Comment: Thanks, I did that before and am now trying to use it ;)

Comment: in your project root type `php artisan serve` then try to visit the page

Comment: Thanks, I actually already have a working project, so i can visit it etc. But when trying to register or login I get "not found". I will try to write register and login functions in RegisterController